# How to find the most similar words from a set of input words by CBOW (GenSim)?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I use GenSim and CBOW for training the corpus. How can I get the most similar words from a set of input words?

For example:
Given a set of input words: ["David", "Mary", "married"]. Can I infer some output words like: "wedding", "husband", "wife", "couple", etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [wv.most_similar](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar) method of your model.

Comment: Hello, what are the positive and negative lists?

Comment: In your case you want all input words to be in the positive list: "positive" to specify the words which should be similar to the output, and "negative" to specify those which should be dissimilar to the output.

Comment: That is really help. I wonder that how does model.wv.most_similar(['a', 'b'], topn=10) count for the most similar words. Suppose we have the most similar word x, so it will be based on the mean of similarity('x', 'a') and similarity('x', 'b') ?

Comment: No, it retrieves the words corresponding to the word embeddings the most similar to the vector ``v = va + vb`` if ``va`` is the word embedding of ``a`` and ``vb`` is the word embedding of ``b``.

Comment: Ok, I will write a custom code for this. Thank for your information.